# Não permitir formulário MODAL sair de dentro do formulário principal

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe3, delphi-xe5

Tenho uma aplicação que possui um formulário principal, do qual chamo os demais. Os formulários que chamo normalmente "formulario.Show;" ficam dentro dentro da área do formulário principal, porem, os que chamo "formulario.showmodal;" ficam sobre o formulário principal. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de deixar o formulário em modal, porem, dentro da área do formulário principal...

Comment: Quando você fala "dentro" do form principal, você quer dizer que a aplicação é MDI?

Comment: isso mesmo @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira

Comment: Acredito não ser possível diretamente pois vai contra o objetivo deste tipo de "organização de janelas", que objetiva alternar entre telas. Talvez executando um loop de eventos dentro do form seja possível simular um form modal, mas teria que analisar o código fonte da classe `TForm` e da classe `TApplication` para entender como o Delphi trabalha com forms modais. Mas out of the box com certeza não há como.